# Android -- Sharing multiple (two) links using chooser

Tags: android, hyperlink, share

I want the user to be able to share a link (to text content online). When shared, I also want a link to the app in the Play Store to appear below said link.

Via email, the shared might look like the following

Email subject: [content subject]

Email body:

[link to content]

Download our app here: 
[link to app in Play Store]

I tried something like this, but it doesn't display the links:

```
    String playStoreUrl = "market://details?id=" +   getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
    ArrayList<String> links = new ArrayList<String>();
    links.add(data.getLink());
    links.add(playStoreUrl);

    Intent sharingIntent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    sharingIntent2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, content.getSubject());
    sharingIntent2.putStringArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, links);
    sharingIntent2.setType("text/plan");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent2, "Share this content"));
```

Any help is much appreciated! There doesn't seem to much documentation on this.

Comment: At the end of the day putting a String ArrayList into your intent isnt going to do anything. You want to put a string with the whole message body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
String YOUR_TEXT_TO_SEND=data.getLink()+"\n"+"Download our app here: "+"[link to app in Play Store]";

intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, YOUR_TEXT_TO_SEND);
```

Comment: Nice! I didn't even think of this.